# when I try Publish my Vue App on Github Pages i getting some Errors in terminal when i run npm run deploy

Tags: vue.js, deployment, github-pages

the Terminal errors

```
fatal: invalid refspec 'main:'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 128
npm ERR! find-a-coach@0.1.0 deploy: `sh deploy.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 128
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the find-a-coach@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mohamed mohamed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-07T18_12_52_349Z-debug.log
```

the Deploy Script

```
    #!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e

npm run build
cd dist
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "New Deployment"
git push -f git@github.com:muojahead/find-a-coach.git main: github-pages
cd -
```

I added The SSH Key To the github settings and the branch which i upload My files on is "main"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to run `npm install` first in the deploy script